# Where the heck is CSVkit?

Tags: python, macos, bash

I installed CSVkit on OSX with `pip install --user csvkit` and it seems to have worked (re-installing) gets me a `Requirement already satisfied` message, but `csvcut` isn't available at my command prompt and `which csvcut` returns nothing.

How do I get csvkit into my path by default?

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? The message after 'Requirement satisfied' should tell you where it is installed. I have csvkit under my Anaconda installation (under User). It doesn't show up with `which`, but `csvclean` works anyway.

Comment: I too have installed under my Anaconda install.  `which csvkit` won't work even with proper install.  What will work is `which csvlook` – or `which` with any other of the csv tools *within* csvkit.  Also, as always, relaunch your terminal before trouble shooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--user` flag should be installing the scripts in `$PYTHONUSERBASE/bin`. If `PYTHONUSERBASE` isn't set, I believe this defaults to `$HOME/.local`.

I see two options:

1. Set `$PYTHONUSERBASE` or look in `$HOME/.local/bin` for the `csvcut` script. Then, add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your path:

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
   ```
2. Run `pip install csvkit` without the `--user` flag, which should put the scripts in your path (probably `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: I don't have root on the machine, unfortunately, so I can only install as User.